# Android twitter4j custom API keys

Tags: java, android, twitter, twitter4j

I am trying to make a twitter client where the user can use there own API keys, but the app crashes. How can I allow the user to set the keys, Here is what I have tried.

How can I catch an exception if the user has not set the keys?

```
package com.kerseykyle.customtweet;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import twitter4j.*;
import twitter4j.auth.AccessToken;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Context mContext;
    Twitter mTwitter;
    static int MAX_COUNT = 140;
    Button btnTweet;
    SharedPreferences prefs;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
        mContext = getApplicationContext();
        mTwitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();

        EditText txtStatus = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TweetData);
        final TextView lblCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.count);

        txtStatus.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                // Display Remaining Character with respective color
                int count = MAX_COUNT - s.length();
                lblCount.setText(Integer.toString(count));
                lblCount.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                if (count < 10) {
                    lblCount.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
                }
                if (count < 0) {
                    lblCount.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                }
                if (count > 0) {
                    Button mSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.postTweet);
                    mSend.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            EditText info = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TweetData);
                            String mUpdateStatus = info.getText().toString();
                            try {
                                Status status = mTwitter
                                        .updateStatus(mUpdateStatus);
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                        "Updating status", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                        .show();
                            } catch (TwitterException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }

            }

        });

    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    //called when an option is clicked
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        switch(item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.item_prefs:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, PrefsActivity.class));
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,String key) {
        mTwitter.setOAuthConsumer(prefs.getString("consumer_key", ""), prefs.getString("consumer_secret", ""));
        String token = prefs.getString("access_token", "");
        String secret = prefs.getString("secret_access_token", "");
        AccessToken at = new AccessToken(token, secret);
        mTwitter.setOAuthAccessToken(at);
    }

}
```

Here is the logcat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(14095): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(14095): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: twitter4j.TwitterFactory
E/AndroidRuntime(14095):    at com.kerseykyle.customtweet.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:36)
E/AndroidRuntime(14095):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
E/AndroidRuntime(14095):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
E/AndroidRuntime(14095):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
E/AndroidRuntime(14095):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
E/AndroidRuntime(14095):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime(14095):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
E/AndroidRuntime(14095):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(14095):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime(14095):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
E/AndroidRuntime(14095):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(14095):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime(14095):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
E/AndroidRuntime(14095):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
E/AndroidRuntime(14095):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
W/ActivityManager(  145):   Force finishing activity com.kerseykyle.customtweet/.MainActivity
```

Answer (score 1):

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: twitter4j.TwitterFactory

This error probably generated because of twitter4j-core.jar or twitter4j-stream.jar are not available into your project build path. Try to check it.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be as simple as the name of your library folder.  Make sure it is named "libs". Then put the twitter4j jar there.

Comment: I added the twitter4j jar to my project.